# Cannot click to customized checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, flexbox

Cannot click on my customized checkbox.

I've used [this](https://codepen.io/thirdtiu/pen/NPGbOb) example as a base in my simple [app](https://sbr-fst-task.herokuapp.com/) but it doesn't work (i've broken something)

I've tried to change:

- `z-index` for elements near checkbox
- `block` to `flex`
- google it about 2 hours

but it doesn't work.

Code below perfectly works in: codepen, stack but with my changes doesn't work in my app

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before {
  background: #fff;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:before {
  content: "\2713";
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="custom_checkbox" value="custom_checkbox">
<label for="custom_checkbox">My Custom Checkbox</label>
```

Fast links:

- [my app](https://sbr-fst-task.herokuapp.com/)
- [example of checkbox on codepen](https://codepen.io/thirdtiu/pen/NPGbOb)

Comment: everything is fine everywhere ...

Answer (score 4):

Keep the `id` of `input` same as the `for` attribute on the `label`.

For more information read this https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/html-label/

```
<div class="stops__filter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="all">
    <label for="all">Показать все</label>
</div>
```